# Developer.facebook.com asks for Data Deletion Url

Tags: android, ios, facebook, web, facebook-login

When trying to switch from developer to live mode, `developer.facebook.com` gave me this warning: 
`Before switching to live mode, you must provide both a valid Privacy Policy URL and data deletion information. Update this information in Basic Settings on App Dashboard`
I have provided my Privacy policy url, but I dont know what to put here:
[image]

To be honest, I dont need this for live app, just for fb login on my test app, but when I try to login with Facebook, I got the error `This app is still in development mode`. Ok fb, I know...

Comment: Did you click on the little i? It is a URL that Facebook can call when a user requests to delete all of their data; You need to delete all of the associated user's data

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fixed by putting the same URL as it's in a Privacy Policy field.
However, this should not be the right fix. But the app was made for testing purposes only.

Comment: How's your app @stackich is it still on? You not blocked?

Comment: Hi @John, as I said in the previous comment, the app was made just for testing purposes. It is not live.